# Configure sidekiq on rails app with docker is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, sidekiq

I am defining containers for my rails app, one for the db and one for sidekiq, the db service can be found from my web app, but it seems that sidekiq can't, here is docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  db:
  image: postgres:13.3
  volumes:
    - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=user
    - POSTGRES_DB=db
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ps


  worker:
    << : *common-worker-settings
    command: >
      dumb-init bash -c "
      (bundle check || bundle install) &&
      bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml"
  depends_on:
    - db
```

And here is the error when I try to access the database from within sidekiq container.

```
connections on Unix domain socket \\\"/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432\\\"?\\n\",\"error_class\":\"ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

Comment: does your database name `db` ?

Comment: What is the command u run to  access the database from within sidekiq container ?

Comment: The contents of the `&common-worker-settings` are pretty important here, since that's probably where the database configuration is.  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve], including _all_ of the code necessary to demonstrate the issue (ideally a working `docker-compose.yml` file)?  (Why do you need to repeat `bundle install` when you start the container?)